# Product trademark name begs for class/namespace with same name

Tags: c#, .net

> ### Author post-edit: Chosen solution
>
> #### (Original question remains below this box)
>
> **SUMMARY: You SHOULD NOT name a class the same as its namespace. Therefore should a product name be used for the namespace or the main class?**
>
> **Chosen solution:** I decided to apply the product name to the namespace and add a suffix to the main class name (e.g., __Module).
>
> **Rationale:** Visual Studio defaults to using the project name for the namespace, assembly name, as well as the actual deliverable .exe or .dll -- These are the most visible items so I think it makes sense to name the namespace after my product name, then do as Jon Skeet recommends in his answer and name the main class as ___Main or __Program or __Module. No one right answer I suppose.

---

Original question:

I *COMPLETELY* GET IT-- **DON'T NAME A CLASS THE SAME AS ITS NAMESPACE!**

This is almost a duplicate question... except I've spent hours reading articles (see below) and can't find or think of a solution that seems right.

Say I have a product called the `ACME Foobarinator`. It has a couple related types (e.g., settings, enums) but not enough to call for any sort of namespace hierarchy.

It makes sense to create a single product namespace and throw everything into it:

```
namespace Acme.Web.Foobarinator
{
    public class Foobarinator { } // BAD! Same name as namespace!
    public class FoobarinatorInfo { }
    public enum Mode { Disabled, Enabled }
}
```

**BAD!!!** Both namespace and class name are the same!!

But, I'd also like the main class to be `Foobarinator` because it's the trademark product name and I'd like consumers to use it by trademark name: `var fb = new Foobarinator();`

**Option 1:** Eliminate the product namespace, promoting all types to the parent namespace. But this pollutes the parent namespace with types that are specific to the product (and not necessarily all public types). As the product evolves, the pollution stands to increase!

```
namespace Acme.Web
{
    public class Foobarinator { }
    public class FoobarinatorInfo { }
    public enum FoobarinatorMode { Disabled, Enabled }
    // More pollution in future...
}
```

**Option 2:** Add needless suffix to the main class. But this obfuscates the product trademark name!

```
namespace Acme.Web.Foobarinator
{
    public class FoobarinatorMain { } // Not the name of the product!
    public class FoobarinatorInfo { }
    public enum Mode { Disabled, Enabled }
}
```

**Option 3:** Use child classes/types for the related types. However, encapsulating everything in one class eventually violates separation of concerns as the product evolves:

```
namespace Acme.Web
{
    public class Foobarinator
    {
        public class FoobarinatorInfo { }
        public enum Mode { Disabled, Enabled }
    }
}
```

## YOUR THOUGHTS?

Where do I compromise?

> Related questions and articles:
>
> [How to avoid having the same name for a class and it's namespace, such as Technology.Technology?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158092/)
>
> [Should a class have the same name as the namespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1803744/)
>
> [Namespace with same name as a class name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7793956/)
>
> [Should a class have the same name as the namespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1803744/)
>
> http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2010/03/09/do-not-name-a-class-the-same-as-its-namespace-part-one.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use:

```
namespace Acme.Web.Foobarinator
{
    public class Program { } // The entry point
    public class FoobarinatorInfo { }
    public enum Mode { Disabled, Enabled }
}
```

or even:

```
namespace Acme.Web.Foobarinator
{
    public class EntryPoint { }
    public class FoobarinatorInfo { }
    public enum Mode { Disabled, Enabled }
}
```

The first is the Visual Studio default (at least for some project types) and the second makes it crystal clear what the role of the class is.

Comment: Ditto this - and I'd lean toward the second one. I like to think of the namespace as a category, and the class name is a description of a particular chunk of functionality within that category. I think the desire to have the main class be named "Foobarinator" is a bit fallacious. Calling it something like "EntryPoint" is a much clearer description.

Comment: In reality it's an HTTP Module. Does `Acme.Web.Foobarinator.HttpModule` sound right to you then? I've got a number of these, and many times it's just ONE SINGLE CLASS which just screams for the class `Acme.Web.Foobarinator`. But as soon as you add one or two helper types you start to struggle with needing a child namespace. HENCE, should I have multiple single-class products all called `HttpModule` sitting alone in their respective namespaces --or-- should I have a mix of single classes in `Acme.Web` and child namespaces at the same time?

Comment: @KevinR: It's hard to know without the specific example of what `Foobarinator` really does... can you describe the purpose of the module *without* using the word `Foobarinator`?

Comment: @Jon: I'm working on a URL "canonicalizer" HTTP module. It issues 301 Redirects to correct uppercase, trailing slash, hostname, and more. It is cleverly named "Canonicalizer" and will be offered to the community (free) at canonicalizer.com. Everything was great as `Tek4.Web.HttpModule.Canonicalizer` until I needed to add a couple enums and a `CanonicalizerContext` class. Do I throw those types into the parent namespace? If so, what happens if things later evolve to a dozen or more types?

Comment: I wouldn't use `HttpModule` in the namespace name given that you're using the `HttpModule` class as well :) But I'd consider `CanonicalizingModule` or something like that. I'm not sure, to be honest...

Comment: Haha! I'm not sure either! How about namespace `Tek4.Web.HttpModule.CanonicalizerModule` and class `Canonicalizer`? Or just namespace `Tek4.Web.CanonicalizerModule` but that throws all my HttpModules in with all other web products. Argh! I'm spending hours in pain over a naming decision!! It's because I want a consistent hierarchy for everything I produce. I need a beer. Guinness anyone?

Comment: OKAY, I'm taking a cue from Microsoft's Url routing module: `System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule`. I'm going with namespace `Tek4.Web.Modules.Canonicalizer' and class `CanonicalizerModule`. Thanks for all that let me bounce this off you.

Answer (score 1):

Create a more specific namespace that says what the classes are for:

```
namespace Acme.Web.Foobarinator.Client {
   public class FoobarinatorInfo { }
   public enum Mode { Disabled, Enabled }
  public class Foobarinator { }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would change the name of the namespace to be descriptive of the product rather than the name of the product.  So if the Foobarinator has to do with graphics, make your namespace `Acme.Web.Graphics`.

Comment: So, `Acme.Web.HttpModule` in this case. Except I have multiple HttpModule products. So this is basically Option #1 and the question is whether or not to "pollute" `Acme.Web.HttpModule` with all the helper types that belong to separate products.

Comment: As I wrote to HardCode -- Visual Studio defaults to using the project name for the namespace, assembly name, and the .exe or .dll -- These are the most visible items so I think it makes sense to name the namespace after my product name, then do as Jon Skeet recommends and name the main class as ___Main or __Program or __Module. If the product included sub-functions I might then use *.Graphics, etc. for sub-namespaces. No right answer I suppose. Thx for your input.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use the plural. I tend to do this, even though I don't have actual trademarked product names in my namespaces.

For example, suppose you have a ticketing system:

```
namespace Acme.Web.Tickets
{
    public class Ticket { }
    public class TicketInfo { }
    public enum Mode { Disabled, Enabled }
}
```

You could apply that to your product:

```
namespace Acme.Web.Foobarinators
{
    public class Foobarinator { }
    public class FoobarinatorInfo { }
    public enum Mode { Disabled, Enabled }
}
```

Comment: FYI-- "Common law trademark" applies any time you use and claim a mark, so if you wanted to claim Foobarinator, all you do is use it in commerce and claim it as Foobarinator(TM). You shouldn't "dilute" your usage by calling it different things all the time (e.g., plural). Visual Studio defaults to using the project name as the namespace, assembly name, and the .exe or .dll -- thus I'm going to name the namespace after my product name. I agree with Jon Skeet that the main class can be decorated as ___Main or __Program or __Module. Thx for your input.